# Apache FilesMatch directive - "Multiple arguments not (yet) supported"

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

What the heck... There's only one argument, the regex.

Earlier in the file, I denied all.
Now I just want to allow access to index.php, as well as images, css, and javascript.

```
<FilesMatch ~ "(?i:index.php|\.gif|\.jp?g|\.png|\.css|\.js)$" >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Help.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like two arguments to me. Remove the `~` and you'll have one argument again :)